# Correcting an old python code for creating Image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

as the title suggest, I have here an old piece of python code that was working in the previous version (2.7) but isn't anymore.
The code defines a function that creates, from a given array containing 0, 1 and 2 only, an RGB image with the three colors in the "colors" RGB tuples array.
Here's the code :

```
def create_image (A,n,name):
    colors = [(0,128,0),(255,48,29),(48,48,48)]
    colors = [''.join([chr(x)for x in color]) for color in colors]
    img_str=''
    for line in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            img_str += colors [A[line][col]]
            img = Image.fromstring('RGB',(n,n),img_str)
            img.save(name)
    return True
```

But in the latest version, it gives me the following error message :

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-c2af90f0caf4> in <module>()
----> 1 create_image(T,5,'test.png')

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code test.py in create_image(A, n, b)
    105             img_str += colors [A[line][col]]
--> 106             img = Image.fromstring('RGB',(n,n),img_str)
    107             img.save(b)

C:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in fromstring(*args, **kw)
   2075 def fromstring(*args, **kw):
   2076     raise Exception("fromstring() has been removed. " +
-> 2077                     "Please call frombytes() instead.")
   2078 
   2079 

Exception: fromstring() has been removed. Please call frombytes() instead.
```

Would be grateful if somebody could fix this for me.

Comment: Are you unclear what you're supposed to be doing? The error message *tells you!*

Comment: Never used frombytes() before, si I honestly have no idea what to change. Simply changing fromstring() to frombytes() gives another error message :

C:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, *args)

    739         d = _getdecoder(self.mode, decoder_name, args)
    740         d.setimage(self.im)
--> 741         s = d.decode(data)
    742 
    743         if s[0] >= 0:

TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Then fix that error message, and continue until you don't have any. Welcome to software development!

Comment: Strings in Python 3 are Unicode strings, so you _also_ need to change `colors = [''.join([chr(x)for x in color]) for color in colors]` to create a list of `bytes` objects. You can do that with `colors = [bytes(color) for color in colors]` or `colors = list(map(bytes, colors))`. Or just delete that line & replace the previous line with `colors = [bytes((0,128,0)), bytes((255,48,29)), bytes((48,48,48))]`.

Comment: This got rid of the previous error, but gives this :
    TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: `img_str` also needs to be bytes, not a string. You can do that with `img_str = b''`. And I just noticed that the code in your double  loop looks wrong. I'm pretty sure that only the  `img_str += colors [A[line][col]]` line should be in the loops. The conversion and saving should be outside the loops. BTW, building up a string or bytestring by repeated concatenation like that is pretty inefficient. Once you get this stuff functioning correctly you should try to rewrite that.

Comment: I've put the info from my previous comments into an actual answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal strings in Python 2 are simple byte strings, but in Python 3 they are Unicode strings. So to do this sort of byte-level manipulation in Python 3 you can't use normal strings, you need to use the Python 3 `bytes` object; there is also a `bytearray` object that is useful for these sorts of tasks.

Here's some code that shows you how to do the `bytes` manipulations you need to perform this task in Python 3.

```
colors = [(0,128,0), (255,48,29), (48,48,48)]
colors = [bytes(color) for color in colors]
print(colors)

# Some fake image data
data = [[(u+v) % 3 for u in range(4)] for v in range(3)]
print(data)

# Three ways to convert the palette numbers in `data` to RGB bytes

# By concatenation 
img_str = b''
for row in data:
    for col in row:
        img_str += colors[col]
print(img_str)

# By joining the RGB bytes objects
a = b''.join([colors[col] for row in data for col in row])
print(a)

# By splitting the RGB bytes objects and building 
# a new bytes object of the whole image
b = bytes(k for row in data for col in row for k in colors[col])
print(b)
```

**output**

```
[b'\x00\x80\x00', b'\xff0\x1d', b'000']
[[0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1, 2]]
b'\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000'
b'\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000'
b'\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000\x00\x80\x00\xff0\x1d000'
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, Python 3 strings are Unicode strings (whereas Python 2 strings are bytearrays). Since the interpreter can't convert a 'bytes' object to a str *implicitly*, do it *explicitly*.